# 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy, could somebody help me find the problem

Tags: cross-domain

**I'm getting this error:**

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///Users/jonathanguerrero/Documents/GitHub/scoreboard_proj/app.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

**This is my code:**

````
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Scoreboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 1):

install Live server extention on your editor then run it. and it will work